# unable to install grub in /dev/sda Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 18.10, bootloader

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu with windows 10 so I made 3 partitions a root, swap and a bios but it's saying the bootloader failed I can choose a different device but I tried my hard drive but that didn't work or continue with no bootloader or cancel what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: If Windows pre-installed it will be UEFI, and then are you installing in UEFI boot mode? With UEFI you do not need bios_grub. And new versions of Ubuntu use swap file, so no swap partition required, but it will be used if found. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have windows boot, which also has its own partition for boot, in this case you should not assign another boot partition for boot because they are not compatible.  Doing so may damage your windows boot or ubuntu boot. So if you manually configuration ubuntu alongside windows, all you have to do is to assign your root and/or swap.